# Scope creation and batarang

Tags: angularjs, batarang

Consider the following:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Exploring directives</title>
</head>
<body> 

  <my-directive>
    Some text
  </my-directive>
  {{Info.Version}}
  <script type="text/ng-template" id='my-directive.html'>
    <div>Hello, {{Info.Version}}</div>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.Info = {};
  $rootScope.Info.Name = 'rootScope';
  $rootScope.Info.Version = '1.0.0.1';
});
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {    
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
    scope: false
  };
});
```

**Batarang**

[image]

From what I have seen, $rootScope is never displayed (but I'm guessing it would be labeled **Scope (001)** if it was).

When I change scope to true in the **JS**:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {    
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
    scope: true
  };
});
```

It *appears* that $rootScope is pushed down to **Scope (002)**:

[image]

Can somebody please explain what is happening? Why does $rootScope appear to be pushed down? What is above it then? Here is jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/udALigA/1/

Comment: Did you ever figure out why rootScope doesn't show up or why it shows up with an id of 002 instead of 001?

Comment: Not yet but would like to hear the answer.

Answer (score 0):

normally directives create their own `scope` (in this case `Scope (002)`), but when you set `scope: true` in `myDirective` it will inherit the `scope` of the parent element.

at least, that's what i'm assuming is happening here as I've never seen it done that way before. Normally you would use scope to define certain variables within your directive so that you could pass in parameters with the html tag like so:

```
<my-directive someVar="true">
  Some text
</my-directive>
```

then you could pull the value of `someVar` into the directive by using:

```
scope: {
  someVar: '@' //or '=' if you wanted two-way binding
}
```

then you could use `someVar` in a controller that you linked to the directive.

a more common way of pulling down the scope of the parent element is by using the `transclude` assignment in the directive:

```
transclude: true
```